# Mathematical way of saying "repeat this process (calculation) x amount of times"

Tags: soft-question, notation

When we want to sum up some numbers in math, we don't just explicitly write down in plain text "sum up all the following, where *i* starts as 2 and then is continuesly incremented all the way up to and with 5". Instead we use the sigma symbol to indicate just that.

Like the case of the sigma symbol, how would I mathematically express that a certain process, or calculation, should be repeated x amount of times?

Example: (context: neural network)

You will in a feedforward neural network have to calculate the output and then update all of the weights a lot of times (easily exceeds 1000 iterations). Now instead of writing this out in words, is there a mathematical way of expressing this as there were with the case of the sigma symbol?

Comment: **_Iterate_** is a word commonly used for that.

Comment: @BruceET Iterate is plain english and so might not be understood by all people around the world. Is that really the best way of expressing it?

Comment: E.g. You often use: "*^*" instead of "*and*", "*v*" instead of "*or*" , "*>*" instead of "*greater than*" and so on... I imagined it would be logical if there was a way of expressing the conecpt of iterating a certain calculation.

Comment: What's wrong with a pain English word, which can be looked up in a pain English dictionary. Don't claim it's "best", but _iterate_ has almost become a technical term. **_Replicate_** is another possibility, but it has various uses (esp in experimental design). In R statistical software, `replicate` is a function name for such a process. // And a thesaurus would undoubtedly get you others.

Comment: Perhaps see [this](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html)

Comment: In my opinion, plain English is *almost always* better than mathematical symbols. I think symbols should only be used in the explicit absence of a nice way of expressing in plain language. That being said, for a function $f$, often times $f^{100}$ can mean $f(f(f...x...)))$ 100 times, although even that needs to be clarified in english that you don't mean exponentiation.

Comment: I've seen $f^{(n)}$ used to mean $n$-fold composition, as opposed to exponentiation.